# List index out of range error : webscraping with Beautifoul Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the live departure table from [this website](https://shop.caremar.it/it/prossime-partenze/) using beautiful soup.

I've tried the following:

```
caremar_live_departures_table = list(soup.select('.table-booking-history tr'))
caremar_live_departures_data = []
for tr in caremar_live_departures_table:
    td = tr.select('td')
    caremar_live_departures_data.append({
    'DEPARTURE PORT': td[1].select('span span').text,
    'ARRIVAL PORT': td[2].select('span span').text, 
    'DEPARTURE TIME': td[4].select('span').text, 
    'ARRIVAL TIME': td[6].select('span').text,     
    'FEERY TYPE':  td[3].select('span span').text,   
    'STATUS': td[3].select('span span').text   
    })
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
 'DEPARTURE PORT': td[1].select('span span').text,
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The td should be an array, why is it not the case?

Comment: Are you aware that python starts index from 0? If not, then it seems that you are are using index n to access element at n-th position in `td` whereas you should use index (n-1) to access the n-th element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I viewed the source and not every tr in the table has the data you are looking for. If you observe only  with class r1,r2 etc. has got the data you need. Some  only have one td. so, only td[0] is available.  That's why you get  `IndexError`

Also i think you may have got you list indexing wrong. I have tried to fix it as much as possible.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get('https://shop.caremar.it/it/prossime-partenze/')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
caremar_live_departures_table = list(soup.select('.table-booking-history tr[class*="r"]'))
caremar_live_departures_data = []
for tr in caremar_live_departures_table:
    td = tr.select('td')
    caremar_live_departures_data.append({
    'DEPARTURE PORT': td[0].text.strip(),
    'ARRIVAL PORT': td[1].text.strip(),
    'DEPARTURE TIME': td[3].text.strip(),
    'ARRIVAL TIME': td[5].text.strip(),
    'FEERY TYPE':  td[2].text.strip(),
    'STATUS': td[6].text.strip()
    })
print(caremar_live_departures_data)
```

Output

```
[{'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Procida', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Ischia', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '23:00', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '23:30', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Traghetto', 'STATUS': 'Chiuso'}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Ischia', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Procida', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '02:30', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '02:45', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Traghetto', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Ischia', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Pozzuoli', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '02:30', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '03:30', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Traghetto', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Procida', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Pozzuoli', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '03:10', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '03:30', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Traghetto', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Pozzuoli', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Procida', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '04:10', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '05:10', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Traghetto', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Pozzuoli', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Ischia', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '04:10', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '05:40', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Traghetto', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Procida', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Ischia', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '04:40', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '05:40', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Traghetto', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Napoli (Porta di Massa)', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Capri', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '05:35', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '06:25', 'FEERY TYPE': 'TMV', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Napoli (Porta di Massa)', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Procida', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '06:15', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '07:15', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Traghetto', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Napoli (Porta di Massa)', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Ischia', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '06:15', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '07:55', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Traghetto', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Procida', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Napoli (Molo Beverello)', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '06:35', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '07:05', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Aliscafo', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Capri', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Napoli (Porta di Massa)', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '06:40', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '08:00', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Traghetto', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Ischia', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Procida', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '06:45', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '07:00', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Aliscafo', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Ischia', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Napoli (Molo Beverello)', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '06:45', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '07:50', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Aliscafo', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Capri', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Sorrento', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '07:00', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '07:25', 'FEERY TYPE': 'TMV', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Procida', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Napoli (Molo Beverello)', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '07:10', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '07:50', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Aliscafo', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Ischia', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Procida', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '07:20', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '07:50', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Traghetto', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Ischia', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Pozzuoli', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '07:20', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '08:30', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Traghetto', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Procida', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Ischia', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '07:25', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '07:55', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Traghetto', 'STATUS': ''}, {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Napoli (Molo Beverello)', 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Procida', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '07:30', 'ARRIVAL TIME': '08:05', 'FEERY TYPE': 'Aliscafo', 'STATUS': ''}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be easier to pandas and read_html with a specification for columns of interest and order?

```
import pandas as pd

results = pd.read_html('https://shop.caremar.it/it/prossime-partenze/')
df = results[0].dropna(how='all').fillna('')[['Porto di Partenza','Porto di Arrivo','Orario', 'Arrivo', 'Mezzo', 'Stato']]
print(df)
```

Which you could make more explicit with column headers change included:

```
import pandas as pd

results = pd.read_html('https://shop.caremar.it/it/prossime-partenze/')
columnOrder = ['Porto di Partenza','Porto di Arrivo','Orario', 'Arrivo', 'Mezzo', 'Stato']
headers = ['DEPARTURE PORT','ARRIVAL PORT', 'DEPARTURE TIME', 'ARRIVAL TIME', 'FERRY TYPE', 'STATUS']
df = results[0].dropna(how='all').fillna('')[columnOrder]
df.columns = headers
print(df)
```